# Can the verb "find" take an indirect object?

Tags: verbs

Can the verb "find" have an indirect object?

In the song "Up" by INNA (feat Sean Paul) there is this line

> to find myself a love.

Is it incorrect or correct?

Comment: Dictionary result from Cambridge:  "[ + two objects ] Has he found himself a place to live yet?"  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/find

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

That is a valid, if somewhat old-fashioned, usage.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find) defined "find" (in part) as:

> **Definition of *find***
> *transitive verb*
>
> 2a : to come upon by searching or effort *must find a suitable person for the job*
> 2b : to discover by study or experiment *find an answer*
> 2c : to obtain by effort or management *find the time to study*

The [Cambridge definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/find)includes an example:

> [ + two objects ] *Has he found himself a place to live yet?*

One might say or write:

> - I am going to find myself a better house.
> - He is going to find himself a new job.

These sentences have essentially the same meaning as:

> - I am going to find a better house for myself.
> - He is going to find a new job  for himself.

[This Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Find+himself+a+_NOUN_%2CFind+myself+a+_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#) shows that the use of such constructions has been on the rise since the 1980s (in the Google corpus). But they are still a bit unusual in my view, although perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any transitive verb can take an additional indirect object as a *benefactive*.

In full form these will use the preposition *for*:

> He baked a cake for me.

> John cleaned the car for Susan.

but in many cases they allow the same pattern as ditransitive verbs like *give*:

> He baked me a cake.

> She found him a place to live.

> I saved you a chocolate brownie from lunch.

Unfortunately I don't know any rule for deciding which verbs can take the short form for benefactives. (I don't think anybody would find **John cleaned Susan the car* to be acceptable).

But *I found myself a seat/a place to stay/some lunch/ someone to love* are all perfectly normal. I wouldn't call them old-fashioned either.

(*Find myself a love* does seem a little odd to me, but that is because of *a love*, not because of *find myself*. But it's song lyrics, so they often bend the limits a little).